# What's the gender of the languages?

Tags: pronombres, categorías-gramaticales

I try to translate following dialog:

> ¿Hablas inglés?
>
> No, pero probé aprender lo/le/la

Which form is correct?

Comment: Probé a aprenderlo. El verbo probar cuando se refiere a intentar algo usa la preposición 'a'. Ejemplo: Probé a arreglar el coche pero no pude. (Lo intenté.)
Probé la sopa pero no me gustó. (La degusté.)

Comment: Tú escbribes que una forma correcta es "probar a", user139316 que ¨probar + verbo". Nadie le ha echado a él que lo no es verdad. ¿Quién tiene razón?

Comment: @Carlos, tal como está, tu respuesta no responde a la pregunta. Te centras en el uso de la preposición, y daría lo mismo decir "Probé a aprender**lo**" que "Probé a aprender**la**", ya que no explicas nada más ni respondes a la pregunta original sobre géneros. Con lo cual, esto sería un comentario apropiado a la pregunta, pero, tal como está ahora, no es una respuesta.

Comment: @rop, necesitas esa preposición si usas el infinitivo, pero no con un gerundio, por ejemplo: "prueba a soplar más fuerte", "prueba soplando más fuerte". Carlos está en lo correcto en que debería haber una "a" ahí ("probé a aprenderlo/la/le"). En cualquier caso siempre puedes hacer una pregunta nueva (followup question), y posiblemente tendrás más y mejores respuestas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The languages in Spanish are masculine and the suffix -lo is masculine too. Therefore the correct translation is

> No, pero probé aprenderlo.

Comment: Masculine: _inglés_ (referred with _lo_ pronoun). Feminine: _inglesa_ (referred with _la_ pronoun). Therefore, it would be correct also to say: _¿Hablas la lengua ingles**a**? No, pero probé aprender**la**._ (Only to complement your answer)

Comment: @Rodrigo Oh right, correct.

Answer (score 1):

El alemán, el francés, el inglés, el italiano, el ruso, el danés, el latín, el griego...

Aunque una lengua es formalmente femenina, sus denominaciones, en la práctica, son masculinas.

Comment: Una lengua es femenina, pero un idioma es masculino.

Comment: I concur.  See the RAE entry for [**"inglés"**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LaSRFbr) or the Word Reference entry for [**"inglés"**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=inglÃ©s)  In fact, I often use those two sources to clear up any questions I may have about a word's gender.  HTH.